# Substition with negative numbers and exponents

Tags: substitution

I know that (-2)^2 = 4 and -2^2 = -4.

However, I do not know what y^2 is when y is a negative number. Is it -y or (-y)?

I'm asking because I got the following question wrong:

a = -2, b = 6

What is a^2 - b?

I substituted the question as follows:

-2^2 - 6 = -10

However the answers was -2, indicating that it should have been substituted like this:

(-2)^2 - 6 = -2;

There were no brackets in the original question. Does that mean that when you substitute a variable with a negative number that it's bracketed by default?

Comment: Well yes, $a$ is a single object, so it is "bracketed by default."

Comment: Yes, whenever you substitute anything it is bracketed by default.  We often don't even bother bracketing and showing that inbetween step because it is so second nature.  Consider the expression $5x+2$.  If we wanted to give that expression a name, say $y$, and then multiply the expression by two, we would have $(5x+2)\cdot 2$, not $5x+2\cdot 2$.  I.e. $y\cdot 2 = (5x+2)\cdot 2$  not $y\cdot 2 = 5x+2\cdot 2$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $-2^2$ means $-(2\times2)$.  $(-2)^2=-2\times-2$.  The latter of these $2$ representations is $-2$ squared.